# Owl Carousel Slider won't Display in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, owl-carousel

I've been trying to implement the OwlCarousel image slider into my RoR app. The problem is that the slider doesn't seem to be called upon.

This is what it currently outputs (with two images) -

[image: current output]

This is my current relevant code -

In application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require owl.carousel
//= require_tree .
```

In application.css.scss

```
/*
 *= require owl.carousel
 *= require owl.theme
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

In show.html.erb

```
    <div>   
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-md-6 project-right-panel">
            <div id="owl-carousel">
                <% @post_attachments.each do |p| %>
                  <%= image_tag p.avatar_url %>
                  <%= link_to "Edit Attachment", edit_post_attachment_path(p) %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
                autoPlay: 3000,
                item : 3,
                itemsDesktop : [1119,3],
                itemsDesktopSmall : [979, 3]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `item : 3` should be `items: 3`. That might be it. Their demo also looks like they want you to wrap your images in a `div` with class `item`.

Comment: Haha you got it, thanks man. I can't believe I was combing through the whole thing for the past hour with no luck and I completely glossed over that small fact. Can you post it as an answer so that I may mark it as solved?

Comment: Sometimes you just need fresh eyes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item : 3` should be `items: 3`. That might be it. Their demo also looks like they want you to wrap your images in a `div` with class `item`.